# Why does using `or` within an except clause not cause a SyntaxError? Is there a valid use for it?

Tags: python, error-handling

At work, I stumbled upon an `except` clause with an `or` operator:

```py
try:
    # Do something.
except IndexError or KeyError:
    # ErrorHandling
```

I know the exception classes should be passed as a tuple, but it bugged me that it wouldn't even cause a `SyntaxError`.

So first I wanted to investigate whether it actually works. And it doesn't.

```py
>>> def with_or_raise(exc):
...     try:
...         raise exc()
...     except IndexError or KeyError:
...         print('Got ya!')
...

>>> with_or_raise(IndexError)
Got ya!

>>> with_or_raise(KeyError)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in with_or_raise
KeyError
```

So it did not catch the second exception, and looking at the bytecode, it becomes clearer why:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(with_or_raise)
  2           0 SETUP_EXCEPT            10 (to 12)

  3           2 LOAD_FAST                0 (exc)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 RAISE_VARARGS            1
              8 POP_BLOCK
             10 JUMP_FORWARD            32 (to 44)

  4     >>   12 DUP_TOP
             14 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (IndexError)
             16 JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP     20
             18 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (KeyError)
        >>   20 COMPARE_OP              10 (exception match)
             22 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       42
             24 POP_TOP
             26 POP_TOP
             28 POP_TOP

  5          30 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (print)
             32 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Got ya!')
             34 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             36 POP_TOP
             38 POP_EXCEPT
             40 JUMP_FORWARD             2 (to 44)
        >>   42 END_FINALLY
        >>   44 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             46 RETURN_VALUE
```

So we can see, instruction 14 first loads the `IndexError` class onto the stack. Then it checks whether that value is `True`, which it is because of Python truthiness and finally jumps directly to instruction 20 where the `exception match` is done. Since instruction 18 was skipped, `KeyError` was never loaded onto the stack and therefore doesn't match.

I tried with Python 2.7 and 3.6, same result.

But then, why is it valid syntax? I imagine it being one of the following:

1. It's an artifact from a really old version of Python.
2. There is actually a valid use case for using `or` within an `except` clause.
3. It's simply a limitation of the Python parser which might have to accept any expression after the `except` keyword.

My vote is on 3 (given I saw some discussion about a new parser for Python) but I'm hoping someone can confirm that hypothesis. Because if it was 2 for example, I want to know that use case!

Also, I'm a bit clueless on how I'd continue that exploration. I imagine I would have to dig into CPython parser's source code but idk where to find it and maybe there's an easier way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `except e`, `e` can be any valid Python expression:

> ```
> try1_stmt ::=  "try" ":" suite
>                ("except" [expression ["as" identifier]] ":" suite)+
>                ...
> ```
>
> [..] For an `except` clause with an expression, that expression is evaluated, and the clause matches the exception if the resulting object is “compatible” with the exception. An object is compatible with an exception if it is the class or a base class of the exception object or a tuple containing an item compatible with the exception.
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement

The expression `IndexError or KeyError` yields the value `IndexError`. So this is equivalent to:

```
except IndexError:
   ...
```

Comment: Thank you for that lighting fast answer!

Would we consider it a limitation of the parser (i.e. only being able to accept any expression rather that a more specific one) or a deliberate choice in order not to restrict things too much?

Comment: It would seem to me to stick to basic Python principles of simpler being better. Why invent new rules which can only be limiting, when accepting any expression means full freedom without new special cases?

Comment: It's a deliberate choice, allowing one to assemble a tuple of exceptions to catch dynamically, and using using such a value in an `except` statement.

Comment: I guess the reason for limiting the possibilities would be preventing developers from writing code which doesn't do what they intended to. After all, writing `except IndexError or KeyError` looks like a decent thing to write.
However I agree with you that it would be against some other values that Python tries to respect.

Comment: Note that python also allows `var == 1 or 2`, which to the untrained eye also "looks like a decent thing to write".

Answer (score -2):

You should use a n-tuple of types instead of a logical expression (which just returns the first non-false element):

```
def with_or_raise(exc):
  try:
    raise exc()
  except (IndexError,KeyError):
    print('Got ya!')
```

Comment: As stated in the question, I know the exception classes should be passed as a tuple but I was wondering why using `or` was still valid Python.